# Outputting sound via speaker and headphones simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, audio

**Setup**
I have an [Asus Z87-K](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87K/) and am using the on-board audio. It uses the RealTek drivers. I downloaded the latest I believe.
[image: RealTek about dialog]

**Question**
I used to be able to connect both my speakers and headphones and have sound output to both at the same time. With this new board I'm finding that if I plugin my headphones (via front-panel audio connection) that the speaker sound is stopped.

Is there a way for me to set it up so that I can have sound output to both devices? Or am I doomed to have to plug in and unplug the headphones every time.

Answer (score 1):

It might only be possible to have the sound come from one of your machines audio jacks at once. But you can use a splitter such as this to plug in both your speakers and headphones to the same jack. Which would solve your problem.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B001D84CV6?pc_redir=1405466629&robot_redir=1

Comment: This is basically what I use now. You should be able to switch between back and front audio in the sound settings.